# How can you reuse an object property in a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, object, properties

I was trying to reuse an object property in a loop. Is this the right way? I'm always getting an **undefined error**. The properties I want to use are 'field_id' and 'field_text'. I'm not sure if it should be defined as a variable or a string.

[image]

Below is my full code:

```
var client_id = '', company_name = '', vacancy_category_id = '', category_name = '', user_id = '', full_name = '';
    let select2El = {
        params: [{
            'id': '#client_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-clients', 
            'field_id': client_id, 
            'field_text': company_name, 
            'success_response': $scope.clients
        }, {
            'id': '#clone_client_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-clients', 
            'field_id': client_id, 
            'field_text': company_name,
            'success_response': $scope.clients
        }, {
            'id': '#category_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-categories', 
            'field_id': vacancy_category_id, 
            'field_text': category_name, 
            'success_response': $scope.categories
        }, {
            'id': '#owner_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-users-by-type', 
            'field_id': user_id, 
            'field_text': full_name, 
            'success_response': $scope.users
        }]
    }

    for (var key in select2El.params) {
        var sel = select2El.params[key];
        angular.element(sel['id']).select2({
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: '--Select--',
            ajax: {
                url: sel['url'],
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        search: params.term,
                        page: params.page || 1
                    }
                },
                processResults: function (response, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    return {      
                        results: response.data.map(function (res) {
                            console.log(res);
                            return { id: res.sel['field_id'], 'text': res.sel['field_text'] }
                        }),
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 10) < response.total
                        }
                    };
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    sel['success_response'] = response.data;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The line where the object property has been looped over is this:

```
return { id: res.sel['field_id'], 'text': res.sel['field_text']
```

When I `console.log(res)`, I get this data.
[image]

Comment: You are returning res.sel['field_id']. But, I don't see 'sel' in your console log.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `res.sel` field is `undefined`. From what I understand you want the value `field_id` and `field_text` from the object stored in `select2El.params`.

Try the following code -

```
var client_id = '', company_name = '', vacancy_category_id = '', category_name = '', user_id = '', full_name = '';
    let select2El = {
        params: [{
            'id': '#client_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-clients', 
            'field_id': client_id, 
            'field_text': company_name, 
            'success_response': $scope.clients
        }, {
            'id': '#clone_client_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-clients', 
            'field_id': client_id, 
            'field_text': company_name,
            'success_response': $scope.clients
        }, {
            'id': '#category_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-categories', 
            'field_id': vacancy_category_id, 
            'field_text': category_name, 
            'success_response': $scope.categories
        }, {
            'id': '#owner_id', 
            'url': '/consultant/vacancy/get-users-by-type', 
            'field_id': user_id, 
            'field_text': full_name, 
            'success_response': $scope.users
        }]
    }

    for (let key in select2El.params) {
        let sel = select2El.params[key];
        angular.element(sel['id']).select2({
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: '--Select--',
            ajax: {
                url: sel['url'],
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        search: params.term,
                        page: params.page || 1
                    }
                },
                processResults: function (response, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    return {      
                        results: response.data.map(function (res, index) {
                            console.log(res);
                            return { id: sel['field_id'], 'text': sel['field_text'] }
                        }),
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 10) < response.total
                        }
                    };
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    sel['success_response'] = response.data;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I used `index` inside `.map` to fetch the values of `field_text` and `field_id` from the original object

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Appreciate your help. However, I'm sorry, I tried your code and got this response. https://i.ibb.co/C1T4qqF/2020-12-21-12-57.png

Comment: Futher, I'm trying to make it like `id: res.client_id, 'text': res.company_name`. Is it possible to something like concat an object property from `select2El.params` object?

Comment: I think the problem is occurring because `var` is used which doesn't form block-level closure. I have edited the answer, can you check it?

Comment: Also, you can use `Object.assign` to merge objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Thank you @rudraprasad! Greatly appreciated. By the way, just another quick question. Why is that I encounter an `id` not defined error? https://i.ibb.co/n7S6DbV/2020-12-21-20-16.png

Comment: I'm trying to refactor this code:  `results: response.data.map(function (res) { 
    $scope.formatResults(res.client_id, res.company_name)
}),`

Comment: `$scope.formatResults = function(field_1 = {}, field_2 = {}) {
        return { id: field_1, 'text': field_2 }
}`

Comment: I can already get the `field_1` and `field_2` data.

Comment: I've resorted to another solution instead, just so you know.

Comment: okay! great to know you got it working. ’id’ not defined must have occurred because the variable was not defined before it was used.

Comment: now working. i've made it like this:  `results: response.data.map(function (res) { return $scope.formatResults('client_id', 'company_name', res); }),`

Comment: `$scope.formatResults = function(idKey, textKey, toFormat) {
        return { id: toFormat[idKey], text: toFormat[textKey] };
    }`